# Model which belongs_to can be several models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

This is the situation that I have now:

```
Adword has_many pages
page belongs_to Adword
```

Right now I want to place another Ad provider, and that will also generate pages. So, ideally I want somehow to say something like (this is where I am lost):

```
AdProvider has_many pages
page belongs_to AdProvider
```

Where AdProvider could be Adwords, X, Y - What is the correct way to approach this kind of situations in Rails? RIght now I just have a adword_id attribute in Page, but there will be pages which are not associated to Adword but to another Ad provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

From the doc:

> With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one
>   other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a
>   picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a product
>   model.

Comment: I have read about Polymorphic associations, but how would I use it in my case?

Answer (score 1):

I use Single Table Inheritance (STI) when I want to accomplish this.

"STI should be considered when dealing with model classes that share much of the same functionality and data fields, but you as the developer may want more granular control over extending or adding to each class individually. Rather than duplicate the code over and over for multiple tables (and not being DRY) or forego the flexibility of adding idiosyncratic functionality or methods, STI permits you to use keep your data in a single table while writing specialized functionality."

You can read more about it [here](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @emaillenin you could use polimorphic associations to deal with this.

You can see more about that [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

But you should have in mind that classes sharing this type of association should follow a pattern, or else you could end up with tons of if statements in order to avoid their differences.

However by your description of the relation between AdProvider and Adword, I'm guessing that you are using a STI (Single Table Inheritance) system, so  those similarities are already implied.

Comment: I am not using an STI approach at all. RIght now I just have Adwords, but I need to ad a new AdProvider into the architecture called Adcompz. So, basically, a Page could belong to Adwords or Adcompz instance...

Comment: @HommerSmith I'm not sure what you mean by architeture, but what you are describing seems like a STI structure that has Adcompz as the parent class and Adwords, AdProvider as it's child classes. If not, you should consider it.

Answer (score 0):

This article will help you to choose between Polymorphism and STI approach: [STI](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails)

Below you can find a quote from the article:
"
**3. Do the objects have similar data but different behavior?**

How many database columns are shared by every model? If there are going to be many model-specific columns, you should consider Polymorphic Associations. On the other hand, if a Car, Truck, and Motorcycle all have the same attributes, eg:

```
color
engine_size
price
```

but different method implementations, eg:

```
drivetrain_weight # sums different components
value_after_depreciation(years) # uses different depreciation rates
drivers_license_certifications # references different certifications
```

then Single Table Inheritance is probably a good design choice. If there are only minor differences in a few methods, you may want to “cheat” and go with a Single Class."